# Macbook Pro in 2-screen setup

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

Is it possible to use a Macbook Pro 15" (latest) in a setup where an external LCD is connected and used as the primary screen while at the same time the Macbook's own screen is used as the secondary screen (= extends the primary screen to the right)?

(I'd like to work on a big monitor and use the Macbook screen for auxiliary stuff like Terminal windows.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You have Mavericks installed it's not a problem at all to quickly switch between the primary/secondary screen, because the menubar is present on both screens.

To move the Dock You only need to move your mouse cursor to the bottom of the second screen and then move the mouse down again.

---

EDIT:
On previous OSs you can also change the primary screen in **Preferences** -> **Displays** -> **Arrangements** and move the Menubar (white stripe) to secondary screen. Here you can also change the position of secondary monitor.